# Appium inspector needs solution

Tags: appium

Appium inspector makes connection with iphone which helps to inspect element to write script based on that to perform test automation. But, for ipad, the Appium inspector makes connection but doesn’t render the screen on the inspector which makes it impossible to inspect the element. That is the main problem now which needs a solution.

Comment: (1) You didn't add a screenshot (that we can see). (2) Please don't have code as images (use a Markdown code block instead) (3) [It is frowned upon to add "urgent" to your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest). If you include your code and a bit more info, we may be able to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck posting your question here https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector/issues